# Authenticating to Azure AD with Self Signed Certificate using Xamarin Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Can anyone give me the background on how to Authenticate Azure AD in Xamarin Forms iOS & Android apps with azure self signed certificates.

I am trying to authenticate to azure AD without credentials,I have give a certificate for authentication but I have no clarity on the authentication part.

I saw this  [Guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-certificate-based-authentication-get-started)  from Microsoft. But don't know how to implement the same in client side using Xamarin. Can anyone help me to get some solution for this issue.

I am new to Xamarin & Azure. So any help in the form of some links / Sample are highly appreciated. I searched for a solution in google. But ends up with total confusion.

Comment: Hey Nitha - seems like this is about Azure AD not Azure AD B2C, correct?  They are different products...

Comment: Not sure. Since the application will be distributed to people not part of AD, So I am not sure about removing the scope of b2c. Since the business rule will be business to consumer only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As noted previously, confidential client flows should only be used in middle-tier applications, and devops. Confidential clients contain application secrets, so the industry recommends device apps should not use confidential client flows.

Public client applications typically run on devices or desktop machines. They are not trusted to safely keep application secrets, as they cannot hold configuration time secrets. Based on the information provided (creating a Xamarin iOS and Android app), you might want to look into [public client application authentication](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively---Public-client-application-flows).

Here is a sample app from [ADAL](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-multitarget) that includes Xamarin iOS and Android. 
Here is a link to our wiki with more information on [confidential client flows](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Confidential-client-applications-flows). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

The guide you post in your question is for Office mobile applications such as Microsoft Outlook and Microsoft Word and Exchange ActiveSync (EAS) clients. NOT for the App which you develop.

Azure Active Directory allows an application to use  [certificate credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-certificate-credentials)  for authentication.

Using self signed cert is just like using `client_credentails` flow.

**For Native moblie Application, I don't recommend you using this flow. Because it cannot on-behalf a user directly and moblie app is a public client,not a confidential client.** It's usually used in daemon apps.

If you want to use it, You can use the ADAL to achieve that:

Here is a sample for [Authenticating to Azure AD in daemon apps with certificates](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-daemon-certificate-credential/). You can see how to use ADAL with certificate credentials flow in the `Program.cs` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Program.cs is not meant for Mobile apps right? Can you suggest some mobile samples?

Comment: Hi, @NithaPaul . I don't recommend Mobile App to use this authentication flow. Because Moblile App is a public clinet,not a confidential client. If possible, you shouldn't consider to use this flow on a Mobile App.